# How to add item into a list stored in JSON file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I want to add a dictionary into a list that I have in my JSON file.

```
reading = []
reading["game_review"] = {
    "name" : your_name,
    "time" : round(time_result, 2),
    "level" : level+1
}

with open("stat.json", "a") as stats:
    json.dump(reading, stats)
```

Every time I run the code, another dictionary creates in the JSON file and puts itself next to the dictionary that I already have, I want it to add itself into a list inside a dictionary.

Edited:

```
with open("stat.json", "r") as stat_read:
    reading = json.loads(stat_read.read())

reading["game_review"] = {
    "name" : your_name,
    "time" : round(time_result, 2),
    "level" : level+1
}

with open("stat.json", "a") as stats:
    json.dump(reading, stats)
```

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? `"a"`ppend mode adds to the end of the file.

Comment: And which one of them would add into the list?

Comment: File read and write modes? None of them, they don't care about the layout of the file. You need to parse the old content, update it as desired then write it back out over the file.

Comment: So what should I write now?

Comment: What part of @jonrsharpe's explanation was unclear?

Comment: Please don't put a solution in the question; that's what answers are for. Since your solution didn't add anything that Atreyagaurav's answer didn't already cover, I've removed it. In other situations though, you might consider [posting your own answer](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that, read that file, parse the JSON content then append the JSON in the list. then re-write the file.

suppose a JSON file has the following content

```
{"a": ["b", "c"], "d": "e"}
```

then you can do the following

```
with open("data.json") as jfile:
   current_data = json.load(jfile)

current_data['a'].append('f')

with open("data.json", "w") as jfile:
   json.dump(current_data, jfile)
```

the final content in the file will be

```
{"a": ["b", "c", "f"], "d": "e"}
```